# Play framework and IntelliJ new project creation -- errors

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am looking at Play 2.0 for the first time. I installed it using homebrew

```
~/code $ brew info play
play: stable 2.1.0, HEAD
http://www.playframework.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/play/2.1.0 (3998 files, 254M) *
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/play.rb
```

I create a new project and set it up for IntelliJ (12.0.4)

```
~/code $ play new playtime
...
play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_15 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
...
OK, application playtime is created.
...
~/code $ cd playtime/
~/code/playtime $ play idea
...
...
[info] Created /.../playtime/.idea_modules/playtime.iml
[info] Created /.../playtime/.idea_modules/playtime-build.iml
~/code/playtime $
```

I open IntelliJ and rebuild the project. I get

```
scala: Output path /.../playtime/project/target/scala_2.9.2 is shared between: Module 'playtime-build' production, Module 'playtime-build' tests
Currently external Scala compiler prohibits output path sharing.
Either disable the external build mode or configure separate output paths.
TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to combine compiled classes.
```

- How to make a clean empty project that builds ?
- Why does Play create a -build module ? What is it used for?
- Why does this module reference a Scala 2.9.2 path ?
- Libraries scala-2.9.2 and scala-2.10.0 also created, but not used. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) How to make a clean empty project that builds ?

Play 2.0 plugin for IDEA 12.1 (version 0.2.25 or 0.2.26) will be uploaded soon will be much better in this direction, I hope you will not have problems with compilation here.

2-3) Why does Play create a -build module ? What is it used for?

Build module is created for SBT build file. SBT depends on Scala 2.9.2 (that's why this module requires Scala 2.9.2), so to have better editor for such build file, SBT IDEA plugin creates this module (this is third-party plugin, our own SBT plugin will be implemented soon). However this is not right to create such confusing module, in Play 2.0 plugin 0.2.25 project creation will clean this module. So you will not have this confusing module.

4) scala-2.10.0 library is used in Scala facet for Scala compiler. However Scala compiler is not used in Play 2.0 project, we are using play compiler in our support (with bundled with play SBT compiler), so in general it's not used, but you still have this library, otherwise you will get some error messages from Scala compiler, what is Scala plugin usability problem, you can post new issue about it here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing same issue, Play 2.1.1 RC2, IDEA 12.0.4.